# Java: XXX to UTC and then UTC to XXX

Tags: java, time, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I made a class with name **Time** which stores passed time in **UTC** but you can pass into constructor **time in whatever timezone**...

```
public class Time {

  private long timeInUTC;

  // stores given timeInXXX in UTC
  public Time(long timeInXXX, TimeZone tz)
  {
    timeInUTC = timeInXXX - tz.getOffset(timeInXXX); // <---
  }

  public long get()
  {
    return timeInUTC;
  }

  // gets time according to passed timezone
  public long get(TimeZone tz)
  {
    return timeInUTC + tz.getOffset(timeInUTC);
  }

}
```

Now see the **<--** in **constructor**... I am not sure whether this approach to get time in given timezone from UTC time is right...

Example:

```
long timeUTC = System.currentTimeMillis(); // 1441975581976
// .getRawOffset() is not accurate in this case
// so simply imagine that next line is in fact: long timeCET = 1441971981976;
long timeCET = timeUTC - TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET").getRawOffset(); // 1441971981976

Time t = new Time(timeCET, TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET")); // see constructor definition
System.out.println(t.get()); // expects 1441975581976 (timeUTC)
System.out.println(t.get(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"))); // expects 1441971981976 (timeCET)
```

Thanks for response...

Comment: What do you expect the value to be? Using `long` for a date/time usually refers to the milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which is time-zone neutral. What are you actually trying to achieve here? I would advise using the java.time package in Java 8 or Joda Time rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I added the example... Yes I wanted to use java.time, but I need speed which java.time cannot offer...

Comment: Speed at doing what? I'd be quite surprised to see `java.time` proving to be an actual bottleneck, to be honest. (At least, not without an alternative way of achieving the same goal being available. Currently we don't know what that goal is.) Either way, you should ask yourself what the `long` value really represents. It's clear in the normal usage - it's not clear in your case.

Comment: I know what long represents... simply I need to calculate an **offset** from **UTC time** to shift UTC time to CET time... that's what I want... In real life if I have CET time and when I add there an offset for UTC time, I will get UTC time from CET (offset I can get from getOffset()) but I don't know how it works in reverse... I have UTC time and I need to get CET time... again, I subtract offset from UTC time and I will get CET time... but I am not sure, whether in this case is use of getOffset() appropriate...

Comment: Well I still think this is basically a bad idea, but your code in `get` looks like it should be fine *except* that you're subtracting the offset instead of adding it. The code in the constructor is incorrect because you're passing in a value which *isn't* a milliseconds-since-Unix-epoch into TimeZone.getOffset.

Comment: yes you are probably right with get() and constructor when I read TimeZone docs... but then my problem is in constructor... passed long (although it is unix time but shifted by offset according to the given TimeZone tz) I need to convert (so subtract the offset according to the given TimeZone tz) into UTC long... so I am not sure whether use there getOffset() to get the offset...

Comment: Well one problem is that if your constructor parameter is a local time, it could be ambiguous (occurs twice, with different offsets) or not happen at all due to being skipped. What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: yes, constructor parameter timeInXXX is a local time in the TimeZone as second parameter... For example: if I pass timeInXXX with value 0L and TimeZone(UTC) then the value of property timeInUTC will be 0L... If I pass timeInXXX with value 0L and TimeZone(CET) then the value of property timeInUTC should be 0L - CET offset (-3600000L)... but of course, CET offset can be different according to the period... and I need to get that offset and I am not sure wheter getOffset() is the right way...

Comment: That hasn't answered the concern I've raised about what to do if the "local" time is invalid or ambiguous...